# How do I trap "circuit ID = None" errors in the Stem script "exit_used.py"?

Tags: python, blocked-services, stem

Although the Stem script ["exit_used.py"](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/exit_used.html) runs for a while, eventually it hits "Exception in thread Event Notifier" and stops. Traceback reports that the failing call is:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 2196, in get_circuit
    raise exc
ValueError: Tor presently does not have a circuit with the id of 'None'
```

If I knew Python, I would just trap all "circuit ID = None" errors, and move along. But I don't.

How might I accomplish that?

Background: I'd like to use the Stem script "exit_used.py" to log Tor exits being used while testing load times for various websites (torsocks midori -s https://foo.com). I got the idea from grarpamp's post ["Craigslist now giving Tor the slows, lol"](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2014-May/033119.html) in tor-talk.

**Edit**

I've added a timestamp, and reformatted the output for easy spreadsheet entry.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import functools
import time
from stem import StreamStatus
from stem.control import EventType, Controller

def main():
  print "Tracking requests for tor exits. Press 'enter' to end."
  print

  with Controller.from_port() as controller:
    controller.authenticate()

    stream_listener = functools.partial(stream_event, controller)
    controller.add_event_listener(stream_listener, EventType.STREAM)

    raw_input()  # wait for user to press enter

def stream_event(controller, event):
  if event.status == StreamStatus.SUCCEEDED and event.circ_id:
    circ = controller.get_circuit(event.circ_id)
    exit_fingerprint = circ.path[-1][0]
    exit_relay = controller.get_network_status(exit_fingerprint)
    t = time.localtime()

    print "datetime|%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d % (t.tm_year, t.tm_mon, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec)
    print "website|%s" % (event.target)
    print "exitip|%s" % (exit_relay.address)
    print "exitport|%i" % (exit_relay.or_port)
    print "fingerprint|%s" % exit_relay.fingerprint
    print "nickname|%s" % exit_relay.nickname
    print "locale|%s" % controller.get_info("ip-to-country/%s" % exit_relay.address, 'unknown')
    print

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the catch! Fixed...

https://gitweb.torproject.org/stem.git/commitdiff/f46974987106e3246482158e009491faa07bbae4

Comment: Thank you! I should have just created a ticket at <https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/stem/bugs>, right? Also, how easy would it be to print a timestamp? I know that I need to import "datetime.datetime", and then print "datetime.datetime.now()" in format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". But just how is a mystery to me.